# Rails app not finding Devise functions when mounted from Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, rails-engines

I'm building an Rails Engine to handle all the authentication and authorization across multiple applications. All these application are using Devise atm for their authentication. I want to move this into an engine which then can be mounted in all these applications so that they automatically have all devise functionality.

I followed all the steps from the "Devise in an engine" guide on the devise wiki. **The problem** i'm running in to is that i can't use functions like '*current_user*' and '*new_user_session_path*' in the controllers of my main applications.

The error i'm getting in the main application is:

```
Showing .../main_app/app/views/shared/_header.haml where line #19 raised:
undefined local variable or method `new_user_session_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f1578968040>:0x007f157897b348>

= link_to t('user.login'), new_user_session_path
```

The engine does not have an isolate_namespace. I added Devise as a dependency in the engine.gemspec file and removed Devise from the Gemfile in the main application. The engine is mounted in the main application as:

```
mount Engine::Engine, at: 'idms'
```

In the routes of the engine i have devise configuered as:

```
devise_for :users, {
  class_name: "IdmsGem::User",
  module: :devise
  controllers: { sessions: "devise/sessions" }
}
```

The initializers/devise.rb file is as followed:

```
require 'devise/orm/active_record'

Devise.setup do |config|
  config.router_name = '/idms_gem'
end
```

The user model in the engine:

```
module Engine
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    devise :database_authenticatable
    self.table_name = "users"
  end
end
```

Im using Rails 4.2.1 with Devise 3.5.1 on Ruby 2.2.2.

**My question is**, how can i let my controllers and views in my main applications access functions from devise that is configured in my engine?

Any help is welcome! I have been googling and trying every thing for the last couple of days now.
Thanks every one!

**EDIT:** Rake routes gives the following output:

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                Controller#Action
idms_gem        /idms                                      IdmsGem::Engine

{AND THE REST OF MY MAIN APP ROUTES...}

Routes for IdmsGem::Engine:
    new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)  devise/sessions#new
        user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)  devise/sessions#create
destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format) devise/sessions#destroy
                root GET    /                         devise/sessions#new
```

Comment: What do you see if you rake routes?

Comment: I edited my post with the relevant rake routes output. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to link to the engine's path.  This will try and go to the application's path

```
link_to t('user.login'), new_user_session_path
```

So change it to (I think this is right)

```
link_to t('user.login'), IdmsGem.new_user_session_path
```

Comment: Thanks!! This does work! Is it possible to make it with out the egines path? So just: _'new_user_session_path'_ Would i need to use initializes for my engine?

Comment: You could do something like this in your main sites routes `get 'sign_in', to: 'devise/sessions#new', as: 'new_user_session'` but your duplicating routes and it's not clear what you're doing imo so I'd avoid it and just use the engine path.

Comment: As a note for others, my engine does need the following for this answer to work:
    engine_name 'idms_gem' in my engine.rb file.